# Allow User to Change Text By Clicking Word

Tags: php, database, clickable

I'm trying to use PHP to display a short paragraph of text in which each word can be potentially clicked and changed by the user.

For example: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." The user could click on "jumps" and change it to "walks", either via a popup window form or a menu that appears.

I'd like to use a database to keep track of the changes and maybe display the text in its past iterations in some way, too. I am kind of a novice, so don't be afraid to be specific.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HTML5-capable browsers can do this by default with proper use of `contenteditable` attribute. If you'd like to be backwards-compatible, you'll need to search for some kind of [inline-editing](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery%20inline%20edit) (jQuery) plugin.

Btw at first this has nothing to do with PHP, databases because the user interaction happens at the client side natively with HTML5 or with JavaScript as a fallback. Of course, when editing done, you may want to store the submitted data in a database with the help of PHP.

Comment: That is a fantastic suggestion- Thanks Fabrik! I had no idea HTML5 browsers could do that by default. That makes my project so much easier!

Comment: If you think my answer was useful, please tick the pipe next to it. Of course if you have some specific problem, please tell me, maybe i can help you too.